# Is there a way to add "add a teams meeting" instead of add a Zoom meeting

Tags: outlook, microsoft-teams

I've to use teams for my regular meetings. So I was hoping if there was a way I could add teams meeting from Outlook app directly.

[image: Outlook Screenshot]

Comment: Do you have the same email configured on Outlook which you are using for Teams? If you have same email address then you will get the Add Teams meeting option as well.

Comment: Yes. It's the same email configured. But I couldn't find any options to add teams meeting.

Comment: @ForhadZaman, This is a product related question. You will get better response if you post this question on [Microsoft Teams Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum).